# Bayesian Methods with high number of regressors (high dimensional)

Tags: regression, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, frequentist, high-dimensional

I'm comparing Bayesian (generalized) linear methods vs Frequentist ones in the case when $p>n$ ($p,n$ being respectively *number of regressors*, *number of samples*).

In the frequentist context when $p$ > $n$ I cannot invert the design matrix $X$ since it is not full rank. Of course there are methods like Ridge Regression to deal with this problem, **but I don't want to consider them here**. 
So in that case there is an identifiability issue.

My **question** is this:

**Is there any case in which the same problem** (*impossibility of finding regression coefficients when $p>n$*) **arises in a Bayesian context?**
For instance, considering the simple linear model, when I specify the priors as Normal-Invgamma ([like here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression)) I have no need to invert the design matrix to obtain the posterior parameters, solving in that way the problem which occurs in the frequentist case.

---

I'm dealing with pretty complex multilevel models and I let STAN do the computations, so matrix algebra (which is the problem in the linear context) is not something I care about, may be wrongly. 
Thanks to @Tim I read Michael Betancourt answer in stanusersgroup [look here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103625/when-are-bayesian-methods-preferable-to-frequentist) and what I understood is that the prior imposition constraints the posterior sampling to a convex set, not always solving the identifiability problem,but at least allowing to spot high correlations between the regressors.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Inverting matrices has *nothing* to do with Bayesian vs frequentist methods... Bayesians as well use matrix algebra. Moreover, there are frequentist methods for p > n cases.

Comment: Then please make your question more precise: that you are asking if there are problems with n > p when working with generalized linear models when using Bayesian vs frequentist methods.

Comment: @Tim Do you think the question is clear enough now?Thank you

Comment: Yes, but (1) Bayesian estimation also uses matrix algebra, so this has nothing to do with frequentist methods; (2) it is also about [model identifability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20608/what-is-model-identifiability#).

Comment: Sorry @Tim for asking other questions here, as soon as the context will be clearer to me I'll either modify the question again or remove it: 

where do you use matrix algebra in Bayesian estimation? I mean, I'm working with pretty complex multilevel models and I let STAN do the work. I'm lacking knowledge about matrix algebra in a Bayesian context if not for simple normal-inv.gamma linear models.. Thank you again

Comment: Check e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression

Comment: Yep I checked it, but it refers to a case where, if not using uninformative gpriors, the bayesian models don't have the issue of the frequentist ones. 

Thank you again for the help..